# Add-AzureAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: powershell, azure

In Microsoft Azure PowerShell, when I run the Add-AzureAccount command I get this error:

> Add-AzureAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

I have an Azure Account. 
I am using Azure PowerShell version 0.8.16 and Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my problem here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2015/02/12/get-azurevm-your-azure-credentials-have-not-been-set-up-or-have-expired-please-run-add-azureaccount-to-set-up-your-azure-credentials.aspx

The steps to fix the problem are as follows:

> 1. Remove-AzureAccount
> 2. Clear-AzureProfile
> 3. Add-AzureAccount

Comment: This didn't work for me - my situation is that I don't have permission to the whole subscription - only to a single resource group;  I'm guess that is the problem. Please share if you have a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I used `AddAzureRmAccount` instead of `AddAzureAccount` and it worked. I don't know the root cause and I am still digging into this. I will update this answer once I have something concrete on the lines of a probable root cause.