# Azure/ Powershell "Remove-AzureAccount" Name:?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have been this problem for a couple of days if someone knows please explain to me please,

So, I added-AzureAccount and caused this error

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-AzureAccount
Add-AzureAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

so I googled it and found the solution.

[Add-AzureAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841328/add-azureaccount-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary)

however I have problem here Name:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Remove-AzureAccount
cmdlet Remove-AzureAccount at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Name: kazuaki.mai@
Remove-AzureAccount : User name is not valid.
Parameter name: accountId
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureAccount], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.RemoveAzureAccountCommand
```

So my question is

this part

PS C:\Windows\system32> Remove-AzureAccount
    cmdlet Remove-AzureAccount at command pipeline position 1
    Supply values for the following parameters:
    (Type !? for Help.)
    Name: #what should I put here?

what should I put after Name:______ ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you already try logging into the Azure portal as the linked blog post there suggested? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2015/02/12/get-azurevm-your-azure-credentials-have-not-been-set-up-or-have-expired-please-run-add-azureaccount-to-set-up-your-azure-credentials.aspx

Comment: Could it be an issue with azure PowerShell version (strongly recommend using latest 1.0.1)

Comment: @AmandaLange and@Milen Pavlov

Comment: try with the full email address for your azure account like yourname@mailprovider.com

Comment: @MilenPavlov I did it but it did not work.... like this kazuaki.mai@myemail.net so i asked my co-worker, Do i have to ask him again tommorow, because it seems expire in 12 hours. if expires so I have to do this? Remove-AzureAccount
Clear-AzureProfile
Add-AzureAccount

Comment: Have you also tried `Login-AzureRmAccount` ?